# Lifting class instance in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-systems

Is there a way to "lift" a class instance in Haskell easily?

I've been frequently needing to create, e.g., Num instances for some classes that are just "lifting" the Num structure through the type constructor like this:

```
data SomeType a = SomeCons a

instance (Num a)=>Num SomeCons a where
    (SomeCons x) + (SomeCons y) = SomeCons (x+y)
    negate (SomeCons x) = SomeCons (negate x)
    -- similarly for other functions.
```

Is there a way to avoid this boilerplate and "lift" this Num structure automatically? I usually have to do this with Show and other classes also when I was trying to learn existencials and the compiler wouldn't let me use `deriving(Show)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The generalized newtype deriving extension is what you want here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Main where

newtype SomeType a = SomeCons a deriving (Num, Show, Eq)

main = do
  let a = SomeCons 2
      b = SomeCons 3
  print $ a + b
```

Output:

```
*Main> main
SomeCons 5
```

Comment: Because a newtype cannot add any constructors or fields—it just rewraps an existing type. This ensures that the extension can work with any class, instead of only the classes you can usually derive for any datatype.

Answer (score 5):

GHC implements what you want : [Extensions to the deriving mecanism](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10-latest/html/users_guide/deriving.html).
These modifications are often shown for future standard language extension (As seen on [haskell' wiki](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/NewtypeDeriving))

To Enable this extension, you must use the following pragma

```
{-# GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
```

and then use a deriving on your newtype declaration, as usual

```
data SomeType a = SomeCons a deriving (Num)
```

Answer (score 1):

GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving